# XSLT - Print value of tag but ignore child tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I've been trying to only print "argento" with <xsl:value-of select="." /> but it also prints the values of the children, which is what i'm trying to avoid as i only need the first word basically.

this is the XML document i have

```
<elenco-metalli>
<metallo id='1'> 
    argento
    <simbolo>
        Ag 
    </simbolo>
    <etimologia>
        dal latino:  Argentum
    </etimologia>
    <tipo comune='no'>
    <definizione>
        numero atomico 47
    </definizione>
    <definizione informale='s'> 
        L'argento è un metallo di transizione tenero, bianco e lucido; l'argento è il migliore ...
    </definizione>
    </tipo>
</metallo>
```

i do have have to mention, i cannot change the XML or the template

This is what i tried, along with other XPATH queries like tring to get the first element with [.] but that either prints only the first  element or literally makes the whole page blank

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

<xsl:template match="elenco-metalli">
<html>
<head>
<title>Elenco dei metalli piu comuni</title>

</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="metallo">
        <xsl:sort select="./@id" data-type="number" />

            <tr>
                <th colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="." /></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Etimologia:</td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="definizione" /><xsl:value-of select="etimologia" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Definizione: <xsl:value-of select="definizione" /></td>
                <td>
                    <ul>
                        <xsl:for-each select="definizione">
                            <li>
                                <xsl:value-of select="definizione" />
                            </li>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="spacer" colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i've looked everywhere on the internet but with no success, perhaps i've been asking the wrong questions but i'm not even sure which would be the right ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." />
```

returns the contents of all descendant text nodes of the current `metallo`. If you want only the first child text node, change it to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="text()[1]" />
```